# 'continue' in a list comprehension having a function

Tags: python

How can a `continue` be put in a list comprehension having a function?

The following sample code...

```
import pandas as pd

l = list(pd.Series([1,3,5,0,6,8]))

def inverse(x):

    if x == 0:
        print('not ok')
        continue
    else:
        print('ok')

    return 1/x

[inverse(x) for x in l]
```

...gives:

> SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Expected output is:

```
ok
ok
ok
not ok
ok
ok
[1.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.125]
```

Comment: It can't. Also there's no guarantee that function gets called inside a loop, so the `continue` makes no sense. Do the filter in the list comprehension: `[... if x != 0]`.

Comment: Also, why are you initialising a list from a Series?

Comment: @coldspeed ...was experimenting using numpy / pandas with `np.nan` as one of the elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you absolutely need the print, you can map your function to your list, as follow, and then filter out `None`

You cannot call a `continue` inside the comprehension list unfortunately

```
l = [1,3,5,0,6,8]

def inverse(x):
    if x == 0:
        print('not ok')
        return
    else:
        print('ok')
        return 1/x

print([x for x in map(inverse, l) if x is not None])
```

If you have several conditions, then it's easy to change the `inverse` method

Comment: Realized that it is not possible to use `continue` in a function within list comprehension, as it seems to be a part of while loop. Changed my code to use 
`if`s to manipulate. Liked the way you weeded out the `None` from the final outcome, while printing the `ok`s.